# Hide status bar with overlaying black bar

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, background-service, android-statusbar

I have written an Android 7.0 application which collects sensor data in the background (using a background service). While the sensor recording is running I would like to hide the status bar (i.e. the Wifi symbol, clock etc.).

I thought about adding a black bar over the status bar while the background service is running. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may hide the status bar via `setSystemUiVisibility()`

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

---

***edit***
Please disregard this answer as this will only work for foreground application.
For background application, as far as my limited knowledge, there is no way to set System-wide UI invisible.

Comment: But this only works when the app is in foreground which is not the case here

Comment: @machinery my mistake. if that is the case, there is no way you can use `setSystemUiVisibility()` system-wide.